# logstash filter help to change the escape terms in URI back to normal string

Tags: logstash

I tried to use the ELK stack to do some loglines analysis stuff. In the logstash side, part of the filter configs as follow :

    `#Parsing Apache Logs
    if "_apache_log" in [tags] {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}" }
      }

      date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      }

      kv { 
        field_split => "&?" 
      }

    }`

And my logline:

`172.31.8.12 - -/- [10/Feb/2017:03:07:30 +0000] "GET /audit/beacon/?rt.start=navigation&rt.tstart=1480919576471&rt.bstart=1480919576681&rt.end=1480919576764&t_resp=86&t_page=207&t_done=293&t_other=t_domloaded%7C221%2Cboomerang%7C88%2Cboomr_fb%7C210&r=&nt_red_cnt=0&nt_nav_type=0&nt_nav_st=1480919576471&nt_red_st=0&nt_red_end=0&nt_fet_st=1480919576472&nt_dns_st=1480919576472&nt_dns_end=1480919576472&nt_con_st=1480919576472&nt_con_end=1480919576472&nt_req_st=1480919576556&nt_res_st=1480919576557&nt_res_end=1480919576557&nt_domloading=1480919576557&nt_domint=1480919576692&nt_domcontloaded_st=1480919576692&nt_domcontloaded_end=1480919576693&nt_domcomp=1480919576761&nt_load_st=1480919576765&nt_load_end=1480919576765&nt_unload_st=0&nt_unload_end=0&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdev-test01.london.example.ad%3A2678%2Faudit%2F&v=%25boomerang_version%25&vis.st=visible&ua.plt=Win32&ua.vnd= HTTP/1.0" 200 5`

But i found that, some key/value pairs in the logline with the URI escape term
such as:

`"u" => "http%3A%2F%2Fdev-test01.london.example.ad%3A2678%2Faudit%2F",
"v" => "%25boomerang_version%25",`

I wanna the %3A => : and %2F to /

Is any way to unescape these terms?

Answer (score 0):

After read some docs, i found there is an easy way to help unescape

```
  urldecode {
    all_fields => true
  }
```

Add the urldecode , and set all_fields as true, will help to unescape.